# Calling a procedure from a procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a procedure inside procedure, however the calling procedure is in a different db schema so it's a variable and isn't translating.

```
DECLARE client_database varchar(255);

SET client_database = get_database(_client_id); --this gets the schema the procedure is in

CALL client_database.client_procedure(); --then trying to call the procedure with the db schema variable however it's not translating
```

**Question:** Why isn't `client_database` translating?

Comment: You cannot use variables in place of schema, table, or field identifiers.

Comment: @jordan-davis If you can be more specify with the explanation, It would be great if you share the script procedures using the which schema . How are you calling the procedure from which  database ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `client_procedure`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `server_procedure`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `client_db`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS  `server_db`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `client_db`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `server_db`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `client_db`.`client_procedure`()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT CONCAT('FROM `', DATABASE(), '`');
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `server_db`.`controller_procedure`()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `client_database` VARCHAR(64);
    -> 
    ->   -- This gets the schema the procedure is in
    ->   -- SET `client_database` := `get_database`(`client_id`);
    ->   SET `client_database` := 'client_db';
    -> 
    ->   SET @`call` := CONCAT('CALL `', `client_database`, '`.`client_procedure`');
    ->   PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`call`;
    ->   EXECUTE `stmt`;
    ->   DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `server_db`.`controller_procedure`;
+-----------------------------------+
| CONCAT('FROM `', DATABASE(), '`') |
+-----------------------------------+
| FROM `client_db`                  |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bUQBpEhPRmkyFRzJrVBoXw/1).